# Proving (A\B)\C ⊆ A\(B ∪ C).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Hello im a fresh CS student and am really struggeling with maths. I would be really thankful if somebody can show me how to prove (A\B)\C ⊆ A(B ∪ C) ; If you also have some good videos or tutorials for the CS Maths, I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Check your title and the text, there are different inclusion to prove... Fix it!

Comment: The answers here are too good for it to be worth adding another, but I'll mention the abbreviations $a:=x\in A$ etc. let us prove the result just by verifying a truth-function, in this case $a\land\neg(b\lor c)\to(a\land\neg b)\land\neg c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove an inclusion $X\subset Y$ you (usually) take any $x\in X$ and show that $x\in Y$ too. So take any $x\in (A\setminus B)\setminus C$. By definition of set difference, this means $x\in A\setminus B$ and $x\notin C$. This further means that $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$. By De Morgan's law, $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$ is equivalent to $x\notin B\cup C$. Thus $x\in A$ and $x\notin B\cup C$, which is the same as $x\in A\setminus(B\cup C)$. We have thus proven that $(A\setminus B)\setminus C \subset A\setminus(B\cup C)$.

To summarise, recall the definition of inclusion and set difference. Recall what De Morgan's laws say. Then it's just a matter of putting one and two together.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's well explained. I just didn't know you can use De Morgan on  this -> x∉ B and x∉ C . Using two different math methods is weird. If it would be like this (¬B and ¬C), I'd understand it right away.

Comment: @BeCooler So you could say there's the "logic" De Morgan and the "set" De Morgan. You could view $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$ as $x\in B^c\cap C^c$ or  $\neg(x\in B)\wedge \neg(x\in C)$. Some logician would probably disagree, but it works.